# ArcSDE edits not showing up in ArcGIS Server Geodata Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase

I've got an ArcGIS Server GeoData service against an SDE MSSql database.  When changes are made to the source data, the edits don't appear to show up in the GeoData service.

If I restart the service, edits are available via the geodata service.

Is there something else I should be doing to allow edits to always be available?

---

Further investigation revealed that the service did reflect changes, though how long you have to wait is variable.  Sometimes the delay is two minutes, sometimes 30 minutes.

At this stage, to force the GeoDataService not the cache any data, I've set the "Virtual Output Directory" of the service to be none.  No caching, no problems.  Though not ideal, as when no edits are happening, we don't get the performance improvements that caching offers.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using the REST API to access your data, but have you tried resetting the REST cache to see if that helps?

Comment: Michael's right. How you edit your data is relevant to the troubleshooting of your problem.

Comment: I'm not using the REST API.  I've got custom ArcObjects code running queries against the gaodata service.  It's being edited via a range of sources (ArcMap/other custom data loaders etc).  No edits are done via the GeoData service though.

Comment: It still sounds like caching me be an issue. The only reason I keep going back to that is that restarting the service "fixes" the issue. I would try resetting the REST cache or restart the IIS service to see if that helps (and if it does, I'd _really_ like to see someone's answer as to how to reset IIS or the cache automatically after edits; I've been resorting to manual resets).

Comment: @Michael.  See my update above.  By clearing out the "Virtual Output Directory", you may be able to programatically flush the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service was referencing a versioned Geodatabase.  The key is that contrary to the documentation, when making a connection to a pooled service, you need to manually tell the connection to refresh the version.

Here's a code snippet of my updated connection method.

```
var som = this.Connection.ServerObjectManager;
this.Context = som.CreateServerContext(this.Service, "GeodataServer");

// get the workspace from the GeodataServer
this.DataServer = this.Context.ServerObject as IGeoDataServer;
this.DataServerObjects = this.DataServer as IGeoDataServerObjects;
this.Workspace = this.DataServerObjects.DefaultWorkingWorkspace;

//Refresh the data.
var version = this.Workspace as IVersion;
if (version != null)
{
    version.RefreshVersion();
}
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with a REST based geoprocessing service reading from a versioned gdb. Thanks for the tip on Pooled vs Non-Pooled services! I was having an issue running a 'SELECT' on newly created features, and this discussion lead me to change the service to Non-Pooled, which is working fine now! I wish there was a way to refresh version in a gp model. Maybe there is and I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 1):

One option I've discovered is to force the GeoDataService not to cache any data, I've set the "Virtual Output Directory" of the service to be none. No caching, no problems. Though not ideal, as when no edits are happening, we don't get the performance improvements that caching offers.

==Update==

Further testing suggests that there's still something holding onto data.  So while this looked promising, it's still not the answer.